# module copied vba code will not work in new workbook

Tags: excel, vba, module

The following VBA module works in one workbook (thanks to the help from this forum). But as I copy the module from my first workbook and paste it to a new one, it will not activate. That is, the "Worksheet_Change" event does not seem to trigger in the new workbook. Here's the code. (I do not understand the formatting conventions despite earlier posts. I apologize.)

```
Option Explicit

Function CleanCode(Rng As Range)
    Dim strTemp As String
    Dim n As Long

    For n = 1 To Len(Rng)
        Select Case Asc(Mid(UCase(Rng), n, 1))
            Case 48 To 57, 65 To 90
                strTemp = strTemp & Mid(UCase(Rng), n, 1)
        End Select
    Next
    CleanCode = strTemp
End Function


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim ColA As String
    Dim ColB As String
    Dim CellA As Range
    Dim CellB As Range

    Set CellA = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0)
    Set CellB = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1)

    If Len(CellA.Value) > 0 Then
        ColA = CleanCode(CellA)
        ColB = CleanCode(CellB)

        If (ColA <> ColB) Then
            MsgBox CellB
            CellA.Select
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

A secondary wish is to make the module work for any (active) worksheet in the workbook. But my main concern is why the module works in one workbook and not in another.

Comment: Worksheet_change event belongs in a worksheet module, right click on the sheet tab and select "View Code" that is where the worksheet module is.

Comment: The `ThisWorkbook` code module has a `Workbook_SheetChange` event method you can use to trap a change on any sheet in the workbook.  Eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29439997/using-vba-in-the-workbook-sheetchange-event

Comment: That did it,  @Davesexcel. Thank you.As for my secondary question, using Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Target As Range) did not work.

Comment: @Tim Williams Coincidentally, I was looking at that post when you responded. But I can't find the VBAProject Object List. (It has been quite some time since I last worked with the VBA Editor, bit that'sno excuse

Answer (score 0):

Since it's Worksheet_Change, you should paste in a sheet module, like the image below

[image]