# Is there a way to track changes made in a single tab for excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm wondering if there is a way to track changes made to a single tab, not anything within the workbook? I don't need to know who exactly made the changes, just need to know the last date the tab was changed. My idea is to create multiple tabs with their own trackers. Below is what I have, but this is only tracking changes for the whole workbook:

```
Function LastModified() As Date

   LastModified = ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time")
   
End Function
```

I'm new to VBA so apologies if I'm not clear. Let me know if you need more information.

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to log changes for each worksheet (or for selected sheets) then you can look at the `Workbook_SheetChange` event available in the ThisWorkbook code module (select "Workbook" in the left-hand dropdown and "Change" in the right one)   Eg. see https://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/track-changes.htm

Comment: Previously here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29439997/using-vba-in-the-workbook-sheetchange-event